# Placing an image on top of CSS box content.

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place my logo above a menubar i created in css, but what ever i try the logo always goes below the menu bar, i am trying to achieve a manubar the width of the page with a logo in the centre of the menubar.

My CSS code is ;

```
#bar {  
margin-top:50px;
width: 1920px center;
height: 30px;
background: #2E2E2E;
border: 3px groove #FFD700;   
}

#logo { 
background-image:url(../img/LOGO1.png);
background-size:150px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

and html is;

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="bar">
</div>
<div id="logo">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thankyou for any help

Answer (score 1):

`Z:index` is your friend

http://jsfiddle.net/BrvL2/1/

```
#logo { 
position:absolute;
background-image:url(http://placehold.it/150x150/f16b20/ffffff);
background-size:150px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:999;
top:0px;
margin: 0 auto;
left:0px;
right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Centered the logo, check fiddle

Comment: Logo still isn't centered. You have `margin` declared twice and `auto` doesn't work with `absolute` positioning. I updated your fiddle with the correct css: http://jsfiddle.net/BrvL2/2/

Comment: Perfect !! thank you very much, i will like your post in 3 mins after the timer, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
#bar {  
margin-top:50px;
width: 1920px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #2E2E2E;
border: 3px groove #FFD700;   
    text-align: center;
}

#logo { 
position:relative;
background-image:url(http://placehold.it/150x150/f16b20/ffffff);
background-size:150px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:999;
top:0px;
}

<div id="bar">
<div id="logo">
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the CSS:

```
#wrap {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

#bar {  
    position:relative;    
    margin-top:50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #2E2E2E;
    border: 3px groove #FFD700;   
}

#logo { 
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/150x150/f16b20/ffffff);
    background-size:150px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-75px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    z-index:999;
    top:0px;
}
```

I put in a wrap, so the `#logo` would have a parent container to reference when positioning. This will float the logo in the middle of the menu bar.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BrvL2/3/

Answer (score -1):

alter the 'left:' attribute until it is centered

```
#logo { 
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:45%;
right:0;
z-index:1000;
background-image:url(../img/LOGO1.png);
background-size:150px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
```

}

Comment: You don't need to alter the `left` attribute. You set that at `left:50%` then set `margin-left:` to a negative value half the width of the element you are centering. In this case: `margin-left:-75px`